# Using Confirm() in onbeforeunload() event

Tags: javascript, html

I want a confirm box to come up before unloading a page, and if the user clicks ok there a function needs to be called before leaving the page and if he clicks on cancel it should stay on the same page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (!submitFormOkay) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?")) {
            leavepage();
        } else {
            submitfromokay = true;
            location.reload();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can make this work using JS?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. The only way to somehow accomplish that goal is by returning a *String*-value from your `onbeforeunload` handler. Some browsers (*Chrome* for instance), will use that String and display it in their default warning message. But other browsers, won't use it and just display a standard message, that gives the user a chance to interrupt the page unload.

```
// Chrome will use the 'Y U LEAVING' string in its warning message now
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if(!submitFormOkay) {
        return 'Y U LEAVING ?';
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there anyway I can call my function when the user clicks on 'leave this page' from the message that gets displayed here?

Comment: @ArvindSinghY that is a very vague endeavor. You could fool around with two nested calls to `setTimout()`. What we want to achieve there is, we're setting up a function call in the browsers UI queue, which gets executed before the modal dialog appears. The second (nested) `setTimeout` gets fired when the modal dialog gets closed. Since we don't know whether or not the user choosed to stay or to leave (we just know the dialog got closed), we could set the second timeout to like 1000ms or greater, to assure that unloading will interrupt the call if the user choosed to leave.